# javascript carousel

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I made this javascript code for a simple slider that can be controlled by arrows up/down.

I'm wondering what I could have done better..

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', changeSlide);

var wrap = document.querySelector('#wrap');
var slides = wrap.getElementsByTagName('div');
var slidesCount = wrap.children.length-1;
var i = 0;

slides[i].classList.add('active');
document.querySelector('#current').innerHTML += i+1;
document.querySelector('#total').innerHTML += slidesCount+1;


function changeSlide(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 38) {

        if(i >= slidesCount) {
            i = 0;
        } else(
            i++
        )

    } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {

        if(i <= 0) {
            i = slidesCount;
        } else (
            i--
        )
    }


    for (let index = 0; index < slidesCount+1; index++) {
        slides[index].classList.remove('active');        
    }

    slides[i].classList.add('active');
    document.querySelector('#current').innerHTML = (i+1);
}
```

Here is event html:

```
<body>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css"/>


  <div id = "wrap">

    <div>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/19/Ryan_ten_Doeschate_ODI_batting_graph.svg/1216px-Ryan_ten_Doeschate_ODI_batting_graph.svg.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <img src="https://pmpaspeakingofprecision.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/ismmay2013.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div >
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <img src="https://www.rba.gov.au/speeches/2016/images/sp-so-2016-07-12-graph3.gif" alt="">
    </div>

    <div >
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <img src="https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/-/media/ReserveBank/Images/Key%20graphs/key-graph-mortgage-rates-since-1990.jpg?la=en&hash=B224DD2C76E0B0C2DDC85D3A7D3E9A60B7A73ACC" alt="">
    </div>

    <div >
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <img src="https://realtechwater.com/w_p/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/BOD-Graph-Website.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id = counter>
    <span id="current"></span>
    <span>of</span>
    <span id="total"></span>
  </div>

  <script src="slider.js"></script>
</body>
```

And a little bit of css:

```
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrap > div {
  display: none;
}

#counter {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}

.active {
  display: block!important;
}
```

For those who like codepen, [here is the link](https://codepen.io/pantata/pen/BaBWege).

Answer (score 3):

The main part of code I would focus on is this part with high branch complexity:

> ```
> if (e.keyCode == 38) {
>
>     if(i >= slidesCount) {
>         i = 0;
>     } else(
>         i++
>     )
>
> } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
>
>     if(i <= 0) {
>         i = slidesCount;
>     } else (
>         i--
>     )
> }
> ```

When you realise a carousel has circular navigation, you could take advantage of *modular arithmetic*. Note that you could then just use the actual count, without the `-1` 'hack'.

```
const slidesCount = wrap.children.length;
```

Refactored using modular arithmetic:

```
if (e.keyCode == 38) {
  i = (i + 1) % slidesCount;
} else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
  i = (i - 1 + slidesCount) % slidesCount;
}
```

This could further be refactored using a bi-directional formula:

```
const phase = e.keyCode == 38 ? 1 : e.keyCode == 40 ? -1 : 0;
i = ((i + phase) % slidesCount + slidesCount) % slidesCount;
```

---

When initialising the carousel, you activate the first slide. This exact code is repeated in `changeSlide`.

> ```
> slides[i].classList.add('active');
> document.querySelector('#current').innerHTML += i+1;
> ```

Consider providing a method `activate(index)`, which should also include the code for deactivating the other sliders.

---

Prefer the use of `let` and `const` over `var`. The scope and intention of these keywords are better than the ol' var.

> ```
> var wrap = document.querySelector('#wrap');
> var slides = wrap.getElementsByTagName('div');
> var slidesCount = wrap.children.length-1;
> var i = 0;
> ```

```
const wrap = document.querySelector('#wrap');
const slides = wrap.getElementsByTagName('div');
const slidesCount = wrap.children.length;
let index = 0;
```

Comment: You use _modular arithmic_ twice but did you perhaps mean _arithmetic_?

Comment: Of course, I put that one in for you to find... why else ;-)

Comment: I guess it's a side-effect of that kotlin app about music notes some times ago :-]

Comment: nesting ternaries 

Comment: @LukeRobertson some like it, some don't :) I find this one to be readable.